# Enter "\\\" in a string in python

Tags: python

How to insert "\\\" in a string in python. It seems to give Error

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You can also do this. `print ('\\'*3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because `\` means break in Python.

`\\` equals `\`but if you use 3 you are breaking something again.

Comment: Thanks got it. Using "\\\\\\" does it

Comment: @SagarChand No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

We can insert `\` from single `print('\\')`

so you wanted to type `\\\\\\` then use six `'\\'` to get `'\\\\\\'` such as

```
print('\\\\\\\\\\\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concat option to get as many `\` as you want.

If you want 3 `\` then you can do:

```
print ('\\'*3)
```

If you want 8 `\`, then you can just do:

```
print ('\\'*8)
```

This will eliminate the need to keep typing \\\\ many times.

Here's a way to add it to a variable and use it for printing later:

```
>>> x = 'This is an example for '+'\\'*3+' 3 backslashes'
>>> print (x)
This is an example for \\\ 3 backslashes
```